# Why couldn't the method find the contained inputed array java

Tags: java

The Method:

```
public void findInfo(String name) {

    for (int index = 0; index < names.size(); index++) {
        if ( name.equalsIgnoreCase( (String) names.get(index)) || name.contains(names.get(index)) ) {
            System.out.println("Customer : ");
            System.out.println(name + " " + coins.get(index) + " cents");
            System.out.println("Change : ");
            this.calChange(coins.get(index));
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("Not found");
        break;

    }//end of for loop

}//end of findInfo
```

The Main method:

```
ArrayList<String>names = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer>coins = new ArrayList<Integer>();

System.out.println("Enter the name of the person: ");

names.add("Carter");
names.add("John");
names.add("John");
names.add("Peter");
names.add("Carter");
names.add("Peter");
names.add("John");
names.add("Carter");
System.out.println(names);

System.out.println("\nEnter the coin value of the person: ");

coins.add(20);
coins.add(15);
coins.add(20);
coins.add(10);
coins.add(15);
coins.add(10);
coins.add(55);
coins.add(15);
System.out.println(coins);

//check with user whether to continue adding
System.out.println("\nContinue to add more records? (Y/N)");

List<String> cont = new ArrayList<>();
cont.add("Y");
cont.add("Y");
cont.add("Y");
cont.add("Y");
cont.add("Y");
cont.add("Y");
cont.add("Y");
cont.add("N");
System.out.println(cont);

Change client = new Change(names, coins);

boolean flag = true; 

while(flag) {
    System.out.println("Menu: ");
    System.out.println( "1. Enter a name and display change to be given for each denomination\n" ;

    System.out.println("Select a menu item(1 to 5):");
    int select = keyboard.nextInt();

    if(select == 1) {
v       System.out.println("Find record of name: ");
        String find = keyboard.next();

        client.findInfo(find);
```

The actual output:

```
Select a menu item:
1
Find record of name: 
peter
Not found
```

The correct output should be:

```
Select a menu item(1 to 5):
1
Find record of name: 
peter

Customer : 
peter has 20 cents
Change : 
No. of 20 Cents: 1
```

How can I get this result? /

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies on this statement `break;`, move this out of `for` loop.

Let's understand what you have done wrong, you have made a `logical-error`. When you loop run for `index=0`, you check the name. If name is at `index=0` its well and good.

But if name is not present at `index=0`, `if` statement will become false and the program will straight away come to next statement. This part of the code tells the program to `break`.

So, `for` loop is only executed for first entry in the list. You should use this function definition:

```java
public void findInfo(String name) {

    for (int index = 0; index < names.size(); index++) {
        if ( name.equalsIgnoreCase( (String) names.get(index)) || name.contains(names.get(index)) ) {
            System.out.println("Customer : ");
            System.out.println(name + " " + coins.get(index) + " cents");
            System.out.println("Change : ");
            this.calChange(coins.get(index));
            return;
        }

    }//end of for loop
    System.out.println("Not found");

}//end of findInfo
```

Comment: Your code resolves OP's issue but it will print `"Not found"` even if the name is found.  Also. there's no need to use `break` statement outside a loop or `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "break' statements. This is taking execution out of for loop the time it could not satisfy "  if ( name.equalsIgnoreCase( (String) names.get(index))  || name.contains(names.get(index)) ) "
For that matter, if you put the first name as "Carter' in your code it would run as this is the first element, but not others.
Below is the code after removing the break statement.
Also this "not found" will keep printing in every iteration. So do something about this.

public void findInfo(String name) {

```
    for (int index = 0; index < names.size(); index++) {

        if ( name.equalsIgnoreCase( (String) names.get(index))  || name.contains(names.get(index)) )
        {
            System.out.println("Customer : ");
            System.out.println(name + " " + coins.get(index) + " cents");
            System.out.println("Change : ");
            this.calChange(coins.get(index));

        }

     System.out.println("Not found");


    }//end of for loop

}//end of findInfo
```